# How to make HTTPClient request appear in Symfony profiler?

Tags: symfony4, symfony-http-client

I'm using Symfony 4.4.7 and making http requests with HTTPClient (Symfony\Component\HttpClient\HttpClient) but requests doesn't shown in profiler. How to make this profiler tab work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it.

You should use HttpClient using Dependency Injection then requests will appear in Profiler.

```yaml
// services.yaml
App\Service\SomeService:
    arguments: 
        $httpClient: '@http_client'
```

```php
...

use Symfony\Contracts\HttpClient\HttpClientInterface;
...
class SomeService
{
    protected $httpClient;
    public function __construct(HttpClientInterface $httpClient)
    {
        $this->httpClient = $httpClient;
    }
    ...
}
```